# Ios: remove high light of cancel button

Tags: ios

I'm newbie in Ios.
How can i remove highlight in cancel button of UIALERTVIEW.
Or make the other buttons also highlight.
Can it work for all ios version?

Comment: When do you want this to happen? When the button is pressed?

Comment: NO, just display, because currently, "Cancel" button become bold

Comment: This [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125249/highlight-top-button-in-uialertview) could help you. Looks like you may have to build a custom view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIAlertView` is not customizable the way you want. Use your own alert view system, there are dime a dozen out there that you can customize.

Some of them are "huds" that do a lot more than just fire off a modal alert.