# UIAlertView should highlight different button

Tags: swift, uialertview

I have an `UIAlertView` which highlights the Cancel button, but it should highlight the other one. Switching the buttons is not an option.

This is how I initialised the Alert:

```
let downloadAlert = UIAlertView(title: NSLocalizedString("Title", comment: ""),
                message: NSLocalizedString("Message", comment: ""),
                delegate: self,
                cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""),
                otherButtonTitles: NSLocalizedString("Okay", comment: ""))
```

And this is how it looks:
[image]
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can't simply change the UIAlertView's style. I think you need to access the buttons you want to modify externally. Therefore see the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19125887/3397217).